# How to Make Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.UI.Controls.MultiSelectComboBox Work

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

### What I Try to Achieve:

I'm developing a Visual Studio plugin, and I need a MultiSelectComboBox. I want to fit in with the look and feel of VisualStudio so it seemed a good idea to use their own class for this:

> public class MultiSelectComboBox : UserControl, IComponentConnector, IStyleConnector
>   Name: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.UI.Controls.MultiSelectComboBox
>   Assembly: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Common, Version=12.0.0.0

Microsoft uses this class in their *Code Analysis* page: *View/Other Windows/Code Analysis*.

### The Problem:

Of course it just doesn't work right when I want to use it. :)

Here's a sample code how I used it:

```
public TestClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    multiSelectComboBox.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
    multiSelectComboBox.AllItemsText = "All items";
}
```

And here's the XAML markup:

```xml
<UserControl ...
    xmlns:vsUiControls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Common"
    ...>
    <vsUiControls:MultiSelectComboBox x:Name="multiSelectComboBox"/>
</UserControl>
```

Now the MultiSelectComboBox appear and you can interact with it, however, when you select some items, but not all, the items should be displayed like this: `Item 1; Item 3` (assuming you selected all but *Item 2*). However, the displayed text is just `Item 1Item 3`, totally missing the separator.

The funny thing (that I have overlooked for quite a while) is that if you debug your code and ask for `multiSelectComboBox.SelectedItemsText` it returns the right values separated with the semicolon.

So the question is, if the value is stored right, why is it not displayed correctly when I use it in my code, but right when used by Microsoft on the *Code Analysis* page?

The XAML markup describing the style of MultiSelectComboBox contains only one instance of SelectedItemsText, which is a binding. Please see what I've got from .Net Reflector below:

```xml
<local:MultiSelectComboBox
    p1:UserControl.Name="_this"
    p1:AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=AllItemsText}"
    xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Common,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    ...
    <Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
        <local:CheckComboBox
            CheckComboBox.Name="_comboBox"
            p4:FrameworkElement.Style="{StaticResource ComboStyle}"
            p4:Control.HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            p4:KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue"
            p4:AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ElementName=_this,Path=SelectedItemsText,Mode=OneWay}"
            xmlns:p4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                ...
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </local:CheckComboBox>
    </Grid>
</local:MultiSelectComboBox>
```

I am not sure why `SelectedItemsText` is bound to the `AutomationProperties.Name` (attached?) property, but this is what .Net Reflector gave me. If I debug my code, I can find the semicolon separated values stored in the `Name` property of `CheckedComboxBox` control within the `MultiSelectComboBox`.

The values seem to be stored right, binding seems to work, yet the text displayed to the UI does not contain the separator. I'm just puzzled...

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at decompiled sources and it seems that property SelectedItemsText is used only for UI automation (attached property AutomationProperties.Name). Real display text is showind with this XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="PART_SummaryPartialSelection" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource DropDownTextBlockStyle}" Visibility="{Binding Path=AllItemsSelected, ElementName=_this, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverterNegative}}">
  <ItemsControl Name="PART_Items" Focusable="False" Background="#00FFFFFF" IsHitTestVisible="False" x:Uid="M113" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=_this}" ItemTemplate="{Binding DisplayAreaTemplate, ElementName=_this}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Uid="M115">
        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" x:Uid="M116" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</TextBlock>
```

So it is just horizontal StackPanel with items one by one without any separator. So you will need to modify this template or just add semicolon at your items (looks like Visual Studio does it this way as it shows semicolon event after last item - item1; item2;)

Comment: Thanks Nikolay for pointing out this important section in the XAML. I'll have a look and see how I can make it work.

Comment: What they actually do is almost the same as you predicted, but instead of appending the semicolon after every text, they put 3 elements into the stack panel (Item 1, Item 2, Item 3). All the elements contain 2 parts: the first is a TextBlock with the text representation of the item (e.g. "Item 1"), the second part is a TextBlock too, but this contains only a semicolon. So we have 3 of these on the stack panel.

Comment: But they must do a lot of things, as they have a counter in parenthesis in the Static Analysis, which is removed when they string things together in the "PART_SummaryPartialSelection". So things really start to look ugly, confusing and difficult now.

Comment: I did not mark your answer the solution, though it is very helpful, but I still don't have a working code. :(